# presenting ViewController Programmatically in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

i'm trying to present viewcontroller programmatically in storyboard, i'm using the below mentioned code but it's not working, doesn't give me any response...

```
- (void)buttonPressed
{
NSLog(@"called");

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"123"];

vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: That code looks correct.  Are you sure self.navigationController doesn't equal nil?

Comment: `but it's not working, doesn't give me any response...` Care to elaborate?

Comment: my app has several viewControllers, and i have a custom statusBar and on top of the statusBar, i have a custom "clear" button which fires this method from any viewController.. What i want is that when user taps on the status bar, i need my app to modally bring the viewController with identifier @"123"...

Comment: as you may see, i'm new to appDeveloping & StackOverflow, if i'm missing anything or you have any question, please ask.. .thank you

Comment: Why are you presenting the `vc` from `self.navigationController`? What happens when if you call `[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"called");

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];

    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```